# Bash function to open git repository with browser

Tags: bash, git, github

I'm trying to create a bash function so I can get this.

The user, via terminal, goes to the git project path like:

`/home/daniel/projects/my_super_project`

So the user will type `open` and the browser will open in the github.com like:

`http://github.com/bla/my_super_project.git`

So far I have this code:

```
function teste {
     if [ -d .git ]; then
         remotes=$(git remote -v | awk -F'git@github.com:' '{print $2}' | cut -d" " -f1)
         url="https://github.com/"
         url="$url$($remotes | cut -d" " -f1)"
         # here I'll open the browser
     else
       # git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null;
       echo "Not a git repo"
     fi;
}
```

I check if there is a `.git` folder, if so, I look for the remote origin and get its value that is inside the `remote_url`. I was trying to concatenate the `https://github.com` with the `remote_url` but no success because the terminal think it is a path so I get this:

> bash: bla/my_super_project.git: No such file or directory

How can I concatenate these two values?

Comment: I made this one: https://superuser.com/a/1688501/874562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
function opengit {
    if [ -d .git ]; then
        remotes=$(git remote -v | awk -F'git@github.com:' '{print $2}' | cut -d" " -f1)
        if [ -z "$remotes" ];
        then
            remotes=$(git remote -v | awk -F'https://github.com/' '{print $2}' | cut -d" " -f1)
        fi

        remote_url=$(echo $remotes | cut -d" " -f1)
        url="https://github.com/"
        url="${url}${remote_url}"
        xdg-open $url
    else
      echo "Not a git repo"
    fi;
}
```

Comment: For those that doesn't understand what is happening, OP at first tried to execute the command `$($remotes | cut -d" " -f1)"` with `$(...)` instead of expanding it as he's doing with `${...}`.